# Why is this a cycle or multiple cascade paths?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have an SQL Server table `members` (representing, obviously, a list of member data, such as names, addresses, etc.) and a table `updates`, which is meant to hold previous member data every time a member updates their data.

In both tables, there is a foreign key constraint to the ID column in a third table `countries` (representing a list of country data, linked to in each member’s address). This constraint has `SET NULL` on delete and cascade on update; i.e., if a country gets a new ID in the table, update it here as well; if it’s deleted, just set the column to `NULL`.

In a fourth table `members_shipments` (representing individual shipments sent out to members), there is a foreign key constraint to the ID column in `members`, set to cascade on both update and delete: if a member is deleted, so are all shipments to that member. The shipment table also has a foreign key constraint to the ID column in a fifth table `shipments` (representing ‘rounds’ of things to be shipped to a selection of members).

There are no other foreign key constraints in any of the tables.

I would now like to add a similar constraint to `updates` as the one in `members_shipments`, to the ID column in `members`, so that deleting or updating a member also deletes/updates any earlier data for that member.

When I try to do this, however, I am told that this “may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths”, and I don’t understand why this is.

If adding the constraint worked, the structure would be as illustrated here, with rules given as `delete / update` and the constraint I’m trying to add in magenta:

[image: Table relations]

There are of course two possible ways to cascade into the `updates` table – either update the ID column in `countries` or the one in `members`. But they cascade into different columns, and I’m certain I have multiple constraints of this type in other tables, so I don’t understand why this should be a problem. I also don’t understand why this particular constraint should cause cycles (but then I don’t really understand exactly what that means in practice).

**What is the problem with the intended structure here?**

Comment: Post the DDL of the tables, along with the one that generates the error; that would help us help you.

Comment: Is `updates` a log or history of changes to `members` table? If so it would make more sense to utilise *system versioning* instead of manually maintaining.

Comment: @Larnu DDLs being the entire `CREATE TABLE…` scripts for all five tables? Is that what you mean? That would be pretty huge (and full of irrelevant stuff).

Comment: @Stu Yes, pretty much. I’ve never worked with SQL system versioning, so there’s a good chance I’m reinventing the wheel here. This is a table of members of an external organisation, though, and I need to be able to periodically (based on a cutoff timestamp) send them lists of members who have updated their info so they can sync their member list. Is that easily done with system versioning?

Comment: You don't need to include *all* of the DDL, @JanusBahsJacquet , just enough to create an [mre].

Comment: *Is that easily done with system versioning* - yes; Google and read up on *temporal tables* and [for system_time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15) syntax.